# How many times does the value for column B appear for a value in column A?

Tags: r, match, frequency

I am having the hardest time coming up with a code that lets me match a topic (Column B) to a name (Column A) and create a frequency column for the times B has matched with A (or how many times both have appeared together). Col A and B are codes for longer names.

I thought maybe using the count function from `plyr` but cant make it work. Maybe you can give me an idea of what I could use for a code?

For example I have a table:

| **Col A | Col B** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 38 |
| 2 | 38 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 |

The result that I am looking for is

| **Col A | Col B | freq** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 38 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 38 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 |

So the number 38 has appeared in "1"  two times. 6 has appeared one time.  and so on.
I have 600 rows of data and cant come up with a useful or even a close call code.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Use `count` i.e. `library(dplyr);count(df1, ColA, ColB)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarise and count using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

returns:

```
   col1  col2 count
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     6     1
2     1    38     2
3     2     7     3
4     2     8     1
5     2    38     1
```